# Unable to get attribute when posting to database with cgi field storage

Tags: python, postgresql, cgi

I am able to call the attribute as long as I am not trying to post to the database. However, when I try to post to the db I receive the following error:

> 'psycopg2.extensions.connection' object has no attribute 'execute'

Below is is the line that will display the attribute from the cgi fieldstorage and the line that prompts the error. What am I missing?

I have verified the connection with the db is working on other pages.

```
# works
print "{0}".format(fname)

# doesn't work
cur.execute("select * from seats where seat like '%{0}%'".format(fname))
```

I have created page called funct.py which houses the db connector function.

```
def dbconnector(): db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=.. user=.. password=.. host=..") 
cur = db.cursor()
```

The page in question imports the funct.py page and calls the function.
    from funct import *
    ------
    cur, db = dbconnector()

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be calling execute from the connection object, which is not correct for psycopg2. You need to call it from a cursor object, like below:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='', ...) # your connection properties

with conn.cursor() as cur: # Create a cursor and execute from that
    cur.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM seats WHERE seat ~ %s", # Query with your parameter
        (fname,) # Tuple of your parameter values
    )

conn.close()
```

I'm using the tilde `~` in lieu of `LIKE` - it will do the same thing, but won't require you to wrap your string in percent signs `%`.

Lastly, you should not use `format` for parameters in your query. It is a bad practice for both SQL injection vulnerabilities and issues around escaping quotes. Instead, use the parameters argument within the `execute` function, as I have done above.

Comment: I have imported psycopg2 and created the connector.
    def dbconnector():
        db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=.. user=.. password=.. host=..")
        cur = db.cursor()

I call the function and I am able to post using the example above on another cgi. The pages are also located in the same directory.

    cur.execute("select id from test where name like '%{0}%'".format(name))

Comment: @an_owl - Can you update your question with the code you posted in your comment? It is very hard to read.

Comment: Im not sure what the issue was but its working now.. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻